# Ajax toggle button extender not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, checkbox, togglebutton

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" runat="server" Text="Toggle Visibility" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

and an Ajax toggle button extander:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToggleButtonExtender ID="Ext1" CheckedImageAlternateText="View" TargetControlID="CheckBox1" runat="server" CheckedImageUrl="~/Images/Others/view.png" UncheckedImageAlternateText="Hide" UncheckedImageUrl="~/Images/Others/hide.png" ImageWidth="32" ImageHeight="24" ></ajaxToolkit:ToggleButtonExtender>
```

But it is not working.
The page is loading but with the default checkboxes.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your markup looks okay. Maybe the image paths are wrong?

Answer (score -1):

you can try like this.....

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox myCB = new CheckBox();
        myCB.ID = "myCB";
        myCB.Checked = true;
        myCB.Text = "I like ASP.NET";
        Panel1.Controls.Add(myCB);
        AjaxControlToolkit.ToggleButtonExtender myTBE = new AjaxControlToolkit.ToggleButtonExtender();
        myTBE.TargetControlID = "myCB";
        myTBE.CheckedImageUrl = "ToggleButton_Checked.gif";
        myTBE.UncheckedImageUrl = "ToggleButton_Unchecked.gif";
        myTBE.ImageHeight = 19;
        myTBE.ImageWidth = 19;
        Panel1.Controls.Add(myTBE);                         
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">            
    </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```